# SpringBootTest not falling back to "default" profile with Spring Boot 2.4.3

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

I have a problem with a `@SpringBootTest` integration test that is driving me nuts, I hope there are some Spring gurus around that can shed some light on this issue:

Our integration tests need to have a fully initialized ApplicationContext so we dont run them with any special test profiles. This worked well in all environments. I've just now updated to Spring Boot 2.4.3 (from 2.3.4) and experience a really weird problem:

When I run the test locally (either from the IDE or using `mvn test`) it just runs as expected: As I have no profile to run specified whatsoever he's picking up the default `default` profile as it is also shown on the INFO log output when starting:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.3)
2021-02-25 14:24:29.920  INFO [service-api] [           main] d.r.i.i.s.a.ServiceApiApplicationTest : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-02-25 14:24:31.599  INFO [service-api] [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
...
```

If the same thing is run in our CI pipeline using `mvn test` (well actually it is Gitlab AutoDevOps which utilizes the herokuish java buildpack but i'm pretty sure it boils down to `mvn test`) he does not  use the default `default` profile which is causing problems afterwards:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.3)
2021-03-10 15:31:03.925  INFO [service-api] [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2021-03-10 15:31:04.034  INFO [service-api] [           main] c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Connect Timeout Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888. Will be trying the next url if available
...
```

(You see the problem: we're using Spring Cloud config for every environment *except* default but this is just a follow-up problem, the root cause is that when running in Gitlab CI it just does not use the `default` profile.)

So the question is: What part of the environment makes the magic Spring Boot Context initialization process not going through the standard `org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication#logStartupProfileInfo` code its supposed to go every time (like it is documented in the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications):

> The annotation works by creating the ApplicationContext used in your tests through SpringApplication.

?

This problem just occurs after updating to Spring Boot 2.4.3, with v2.3.4 it worked in Gitlab CI just as fine as locally.

(Oh and i know i can würg-around this issue by specifying the profile on the test using `@ActiveProfiles("default")` but dont you agree that this is horrible?)

Comment: The log output for running it locally with `mvn test` still points to `2.3.4.RELEASE` - just to confirm are you sure locally it works with `2.4.3`?

Comment: thanks for answering, yes i'm sure as I tested it locally before committing it (and thus it got run built by gitlab) - it was just a copy&paste error in the question here, i'll fix that